# canon mx535 doesn't work after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: canon

My canon mx535 did work on ubuntu 16.04 but not after upgrading to 18.04 . my sistem shows it in the "devices" and when I try to print a document the status is "processing" but it doesn't print anything. I've just downloaded the official drivers and installed the rolfbensch PPA from above.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your system shows the printer in the "devices". have you checked system settings in the printer options yet? maybe the printer has disappeared from there and you need to add it again.

Comment: no the printer is there and the print in the queue is still "processing"